# Why does std::vector::get_allocator() return by-value?

Tags: c++, allocator

To my surprise, I got an error when trying to use `std::vector::get_allocator()` with an non-copyable allocator. Why does `std::vector::get_allocator()` return by-value and not by-reference?

```
template<typename T>
class nc_allocator {
public:
    using value_type = T;

    nc_allocator(nc_allocator const&) = delete;
    nc_allocator& operator=(nc_allocator const&) = delete;

    // Other required members.
};

std::vector<int, nc_allocator<int>> v;
// boom: use of deleted function
//           'nc_allocator<T>::nc_allocator(const nc_allocator<T>&) [with T = int]'
v.get_allocator();
```

Comment: I suspect that instances of allocators are supposed to be treated like handles.  Evidence of this is that two allocators are only considered equal if one can delete the other's objects.

Answer (score 7):

> I got an error when trying to use `std::vector::get_allocator()` with an non-copyable allocator.

The standard forbids you to do so.  The allocator requirements in `17.6.3.5` state that an allocator shall be copyable.

```
X a1(a);         Shall not exit via an exception.
                 post: a1 == a
X a1(move(a));   Shall not exit via an exception.
                 post: a1 equals the prior value
                 of a.
```

So return by value is a correct way of returning an allocator, concerning the allocator requirements defined by the standard.

I'm not sure *why* this is a requirement but if noncopyable allocators would have been allowed, the empty base optimization would no more work.

Comment: Strictly speaking this only says that a copy operation shall not exit via an exception; it does not say that it must be possible.

Comment: It says this expression must be valid and this expression is exactly the same as for `CopyConstructible` types. It's even stronger since copying must not throw an exception.

Comment: It is not stronger than the verbatim text "the member get_allocator() returns a copy"

Comment: Well, yes it does. There would have to be a pretty serious bug for the standard to mandate something that it does not make possible.

Answer (score 1):

The standard simply dictates so:

> `[C++11: 23.2.1/7]:` *[..]* In all container types defined in this Clause, the
>   member get_allocator() returns a copy of the allocator used to construct the container or, if that allocator has been replaced, a copy of the most recent replacement *[..]*

I suspect @Vaughn's correct in his hypothesis that allocators are meant to be used as "handles".

By *very* loose analogy, would you ever write a non-copyable functor for use with standard algorithms?

Comment: But why does the standard say so?

Comment: @Zoidberg: Because somebody decided that it must. Trying to rationalise about why X was made with Y property is both non constructive and off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: How does one do this part of the standard "if that allocator has been replaced"?